# Echo part of a string

Tags: php

I have this string: computers,cars,movies,sports,etc...

```
$cars = explode(',', $cars)
```

How can i echo lets say 25 chars from the string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve it using the [`substr`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) function:

```
echo substr($str, 0, 25);
```